# php form to email on scheduled time / date

Tags: php, email, cron

I am going to do a basic form to email script, which is not a problem where you press send and the email goes. but what i want to do is i want to put additional fields in there for date and time and the email will go on that particular date/time. what is the best way to achieve this? 
so for example at tuesday 13:30 i would like this script to run to send the email
send-mail.php?mail_id=4
and tuesday 13:45 send-mail.php?mail_id=5   where mail_id changes the mail recipients, content etc.

do i need to run another script every single minute to check in mysql if there is anything to be send?  like 
select * from mails where datetime = NOW() and if yes do the script? i dont think it is very good option as mysql will run 24/7 .

what are you recommendations

Comment: This question seems a bit primarly opinion based but well... It depends if you give the user the ability to send the email at a precise minute or just 15min ?

Comment: add a cron job with your options. Like min, hour, date, day, month.

Comment: i need precise minute , but now really have to be exact, the options can be 15, 30,45, 00

Comment: Cron job is not automated, one needs to set that for each single user rgistering.

Comment: @T.c.YusufTokgoz then a cron job seems unefficient, unless it is fast to process. A background process would be better... Something like node.js maybe...

Comment: [`man at`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?at)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a cron job that runs every 15 minutes and runs a sql statement like:

```
select * from mails where datetime <= NOW() AND isSent = 0
```

This would send all emails that are less then or equal to the current time. Make sure you update the record so you know it has been sent.

Comment: i thought about this but was not really sure if it was the most logical and effective way. thank you

Comment: No problem. Glad I was able to help.